# Google recaptcha validation with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I am interested to hide resultcaptcha message as soon as the user ticks and verifies the google recaptcha. Only the first part (v.length== 0) works. The else if doesn't work. you can check the form here: https://csandreas1.herokuapp.com

```
if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == 0) // this works
    {
        $('#resultcaptcha').show();
        $('#resultcaptcha').html('<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle w3-text-red fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i> <span class="w3-text-white w3-bold" style="font-size:16px"> Please verify that you are a human</span>');
    }
    else if(grecaptcha.getResponse() == 1)//this doesn't work
    {
        $('#resultcaptcha').hide();
        $('#resultcaptcha').html('');
    }

    else{//submit the form}
```

Comment: Try `v.length > 1` as the response is a token id with length greater than 1

Comment: nope, doesn't work

Comment: Log the response to console and inspect what it actually contains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The above code is inside the form `submit` event handler which will trigger only when "submit" (SEND) button is clicked.

To hide the error message as soon as the captcha is verified, you will need to use the `data-callback` on the captcha element (`class="g-recaptcha"`), which as the name suggests provides a callback to be executed the moment captcha is verified successfully. Here's the [documentation link](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#render_param).

Here's what the code should look like. (I couldn't verify the code with `data-callback` attribute, but it did worked with `grecaptcha.render()` method)

```
<script>
     function captcha_callback(response) {
        if (response.length > 1) {
            $('#resultcaptcha').html('');
        }
    }
</script>

<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="site_key" data-callback="captcha_callback"><div>
```

Also, if you want to reset the captcha again, say clearing the form after it is successfully submitted, you can use: (See [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_api))

```
grecaptcha.reset()
```